# Can't add image after deleting it from Scope ( AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Have a function that adds and delete image

```
$scope.stepsModel = [];

    $scope.imageUpload = function(element){
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = $scope.imageIsLoaded;
        reader.readAsDataURL(element.files[0]);
    }

    $scope.imageIsLoaded = function(e){
        $scope.$apply(function() {
            $scope.stepsModel.push(e.target.result);
        });
    }
    console.log($scope.stepsModel);

    $scope.removeAddImage = function($index){ 
        console.log($index);
    $scope.stepsModel.splice($index,1);     
        }
```

after I using `removeAddImage`. I can't add same  image to the scope.
if I add another image it's adding fine.

after deleting console.log shows [] - empty array but  adding image is not working again. I can add only another image

Comment: can you check your console once, what is happening there?

Comment: what it(console) shows when you add image again after deletion ?

Comment: [] - some thing like that. print empty array but, it wan't load image again

Comment: @ManojLodhi   after trying add image any print in console

Comment: @ManojLodhi , find intresting thing, if I delete image, and add again another image. it's uploading. but after that first image is not uploading

Comment: Use `URL.createObjectURL(files[0])` instead it's [faster](https://jsfiddle.net/fdzmd4mg/2/) then FileReader